# How do I say "x is y kilometres from z"?

Tags: grammar

Very basic grammar but for some reason I cannot easily find an answer online.
For example, "My house is 5km from school."

Kind of like かかります but for distance instead of time.

Comment: _x は z から y キロ離れている。_ or _x から z までは y キロ離れている。_

Answer (score 5):

There are a few common ways to express that.

「[家]{いえ}**は**[学校]{がっこう}**から**5km**のところにあります**。」

「家**から**学校**まで**（**は**）5km**あります**。」

「家**から**学校**まで**（**は**）5km**です**。」

「家**は**学校**から**5km[離]{はな}れています。」

「家**は**学校**から**5km**離れたところにあります**。」

It is hard to say which one is most common.  You will hear them all.

Note: I used "km" for the writing purpose.  When you say these sentences out loud, you will read it as 「キロ」.  From the context, no one will think you are talking about weight.

Comment: Can't the 家は学校から5km離れたところにあります just be abbreviated to 家は学校から5km離れたところです?

Comment: @A.Ellett No, it'd sound like "the house is a place 5km away from the school" or even worse "the house has just moved 5km away from the school".